# AngularJS controller variable not passing to child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following code. I read that directives can inherit objects and variables from their parent scopes. I have a controller with a child directive, but I can't seem to get my `$scope.title` inside my directive.

Why is this?

https://plnkr.co/edit/h4YlRPa5ZWQkwPZ3isjZ?p=preview

```
var mod = angular.module('myApp', []);

mod.controller('myControl', controlFunc).directive('myDirec', direcFunc);

function controlFunc($scope){
  $scope.title = "John Smith";
}
function direcFunc(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<h1>' + $scope.title + '</h1>'
  };
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to see in the plunker?  I see "John Smith".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are trying to access the scope in directive, you must have get console error `$scope is not defined`, as `$scope` isn't directly available in directive.

You can't access variable on HTML directly using `$scope` variable. You should either use angular directive for binding like `ng-bind`/`{{}}`(interpolation directive)  will be helpful in this case.

Your directive template should be like below.

```
function direcFunc(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false, //by default false, means will not create a new scope
    //template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>', //alternative
    template: '<h1 ng-bind="title"></h1>'
  };
}
```

Currently what you are thinking isn't correct, here directive is not creating any kind of child scope. Basically by default directive is using `scope: false` options, which says directive to don't create any scope use the existing one. If you wanted to confirm the directive scope is same as that of controller, then you could put `console.log(scope)` inside directive link function.

```
function direcFunc(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false, //by default false, means will not create a new scope
    //template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>', //alternative
    template: '<h1 ng-bind="title"></h1>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        console.log("Below scope will be same as that of controller");
        console.log(scope);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: So, directive only inherit controller contents if I use `ng-bind` specifically? Is there anyway to make the directive inherit all of the controller's contents instantly?

Comment: I have used the `link` function to `console.log` the scope of the directive and it is the same as the scope of the controller, but why can't I use the `$scope.title` from the controller if its the same scope?

Comment: @GEspinha no.. `ng-bind` is used to print controller scope binding on DOM.. do look at updated. Thanks :)

Comment: @GEspinha you can't inject `$scope` dependency on directive function.. and what you were doing is syntactically wrong.. you need to really clear out your basics by reading this [angular directive basic](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: @GEspinha if you are cleared with approach, then you could accept the answer thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, I guess that makes sense :)